# jquery addClass/removeClass to navigation links based on div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a class to links in the navigation by detecting a div with a specific id, each div is on a different page and located at the top.

If I use this for each individual instance, changing out divs and classes respectively

```
$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#contact').position().top){
        $("#nav .contact a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
});
```

the code works, unless I use that code repeatedly like this

```
$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#contact').position().top){
        $("#nav .contact a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
});

$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#blog').position().top){
        $("#nav .blog a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
});
```

at which point only the first instance works (by first instance I mean it doesn't matter which part I put first, the rest seems to be ignored).
.

I have also tried including them all into one function

```
$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#intro').position().top){
        $("#nav .home a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#services').position().top){
        $("#nav .service a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#contact').position().top){
        $("#nav .contact a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#blog').position().top){
        $("#nav .blog a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
});
```

But yet again only the first instance works.

I've also tried switching out

```
$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

with similar results, except if I use

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

in the second instance the code works for it and the first, but continues to ignore the rest after it no matter what I use.

help please

---

edited

its a wordpress site if that helps

---

solved

I just targeted the individual "#"s with

```
if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
```

If the targeted div exists and has a length greater than 0, I can make the nav links do stuff.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I'm having trouble seeing how these could interfere with each other, unless the "styling" of the `.ur-here` class only applies to the first one.

Comment: Side note: If you find yourself writing things like `$(this).scrollTop()` repeatedly in a function, think about how much work that is, and cache the result to a variable for reuse.

Comment: The site I'm working on isn't online, and I dont know how to replicate multiple pages.

Comment: @ Nicholas: This doesn't require replicating multiple pages (not that that should be a barrier), and linking to the site (as opposed to putting the MCVE in the question) would be off-topic (links rot). Just a single page replicating the scrolling behavior you describe. Reducing things to a minimal test case is fundamental to solving issues.

Comment: @ Nicholas: For example, [this test case](http://jsbin.com/sipehuka/1) succeeds in adding the class as you scroll (naturally you also want to [remove the class](http://jsbin.com/sipehuka/2) when scrolling up)... But I assume your use case must be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make sure that as you scroll either direction, you show the `ur-here` class on the *bottommost* element that the user has scrolled the top of the window into, then: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/sipehuka/3)

```
$(document).on("scroll ready", function() {
    // Remember scrollTop
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Remove the class from all relevant elements
    $("#nav a").removeClass("ur-here");

    // Working from the BOTTOM up, add it to the first matching element
    if (scrollTop >=$('#blog').position().top) {
        $("#nav .blog a").toggleClass("ur-here");
    }
    else if (scrollTop >=$('#contact').position().top) {
        $("#nav .contact a").addClass("ur-here");
    }
    else {
        // ...and so on
    }
});
```

Comment: That's right. I personally recommend to iterate through sections instead of hardcode them one by one: http://jsfiddle.net/TH2D4/

Comment: Thanks for the example, I edited it so that the code would be exactly the same as it would be on my project and it worked great, however when I use it on my project only the first instance works (what would be the bottom div (#blog). I dont need it to scroll, I was just using that as a way to detect a specific div, is there anyway to just detect if a "#" is on a page?